# HID with bidirectional communication

Tags: usb, arduino-micro, hid

I want to build a gamepad [HID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) using the Arduino Micro, and intend to use [Nico’s HID library](https://github.com/NicoHood/HID) for that.

But I would like to send some config info from the PC to the Arduino HID as well.

Can you have a gamepad that not only sends state to the PC, but also receives a configuration from the PC?

I intend to use this with a Linux PC as host.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the configuration side of things will not be part of the gamepad HID.  You will need to set up a second communication channel - be that serial or raw HID - to do the configuration.